# Conflict errors installing own packages located on test.pypi.org, using pip (or pipenv)

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pipenv

I've create my own package using setup.py, and uploaded, for testing, on test.pypi.og. I've 3 versions : 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0.
When I want to install it in a new folder/project, there's this error :

```
ERROR: Cannot install my_package==1.0.0, my_package==1.0.1 and my_package==1.1.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    my_package 1.1.0 depends on pysqlite3
    my_package 1.0.1 depends on flake8
    my_package 1.0.0 depends on flake8

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

But, if I run the command severals times, the name of the packages (depends on ...) change !!??

Part of my setup.py :

```
python_requires=">=3.8, <4",
    packages=find_packages(
        include=["sqlalchemy_module"]
    ),
    install_requires=[
        "requests",
        "pysqlite3",
        "SQLAlchemy",
        "logging",
        "argparse",
        "configparser", ],
    setup_requires=['setuptools'],
    # pip install -e flake8 ... ...
    extras_require={
        "dev": ['flake8', 'black', 'isort', 'tox', 'mccabe', 'pre-commit', 'bumpver']
    },
    tests_require=["pytest", "pytest-cov"],
    package_data={},
    package_dir={"": "."},
```

Thanks
F.

Comment: The same project uploaded on pypi.org works fine. So, Am I wrong saying test.pypi.org is bugged ? :)

Comment: Same problem with testpypi for two recent projects. 
Like Fabrice, the error does not occur if the package is published on pypi. spike2py is now at version 0.2.0, so not sure why I get errors related to previous versions. 

ERROR: Cannot install spike2py-preprocess because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
```terminal
    spike2py 0.1.15 depends on matplotlib
    spike2py 0.1.14 depends on numpy>=1.19.1
    spike2py 0.1.13 depends on matplotlib
    spike2py 0.1.12 depends on numpy>=1.19.1
...
```

Comment: Update: tried pinning version of dependency to most recent version (spike2py==0.2.0), but got the same error message. Not sure why pip flagging dependency issues across previous versions of a package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem in the following book:
[Research Software Engineering with Python](https://merely-useful.tech/py-rse/)

Basically, when trying to install a package on testpypi that contains dependencies that are not available on testpypi, we need to add `--extra-index-url` to our pip command.

As an example, I tried to pip install a package from testpypi with the following command:

```
$ pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ spike2py-preprocess==0.0.2
```

I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot install spike2py-preprocess because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    spike2py 0.1.15 depends on matplotlib
    spike2py 0.1.14 depends on numpy>=1.19.1
    spike2py 0.1.13 depends on matplotlib
    spike2py 0.1.12 depends on numpy>=1.19.1
    spike2py 0.1.11 depends on numpy==1.19.1
    spike2py 0.1.10 depends on numpy==1.19.1
    spike2py 0.1.9 depends on matplotlib>=3.3.1
    spike2py 0.1.7 depends on matplotlib>=3.3.1
    spike2py 0.1.6 depends on matplotlib>=3.3.1
    spike2py 0.1.5 depends on matplotlib>=3.3.1
    spike2py 0.1.4 depends on matplotlib>=3.3.1
    spike2py 0.1.3 depends on matplotlib>=3.3.1
    spike2py 0.1.2 depends on matplotlib>=3.3.1
    spike2py 0.1.1 depends on matplotlib>=3.3.1
    spike2py 0.1.0 depends on matplotlib>=3.3.1

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

However, when I reran the command as follows:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple spike2py-preprocess==0.0.2
```

My package installed as expected.